# Variable always resetting

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a game like mastermind using forms. My problem is that I have a variable $attempts, and I want it to increase every time the user guesses a number, but it seems to always reset to zero so my number of attempts will always be displayed as 1. If it helps here's the code I'm using:

```
$black = 0;
$white = 0;
$answer = array(1,2,3,4);
$tries = array();
$attempts = 0;
if ($process == true)
{
$guess = str_split($_POST['guess']);
if ($guess == $answer)
{
    $black = 4;
} else
{
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {
        if ($guess[$i] == $answer[$i])
        {
            $black = $black + 1;
            $white = $white - 1;
        }
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($guess as $val)
    {
        if (($key = array_search($val, $answer))!==false)
        {
            $result[] = $val;
            unset($answer[$key]);
        }
    }
    $count = count($result);
    $white = $white + $count;
}
}
$chance = implode(" ",$guess);
$attempts += 1;
$try = $attempts.".".$chance.".".$white.".".$black;
array_push($tries, $try);
```

Comment: Do you mean it resets across requests? If so, you need to look into using sessions.

Comment: how are you passing attempts from one page/attempt to the next?  HTML form field?

Comment: Actually this is all in one php file, and yes, i'm using an HTML form field, method 'post'

Answer (score 1):

Are you submitting the form on every guess?  If so you need to set a session variable like:

```
$_SESSION['attempts'] += 1;
```

Just to clarify something that it *seems* you are missing.  A php script is code that runs on the server producing a document (frequently html) to be sent to a client.  Therefore it isn't very interactive accross requests.  If you want code to be ran on the client side you need to use Javascript.  Javascript has the benefit of not needed to pass information accross the internet between client and server.

Comment: yes, and I'm sorry, but where and how do I set the session variable?

Comment: At the place where you have `$attempts=0;` change it to `if (!isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) $_SESSION['attempts']=0;` Then use my code above wherever you have `$attempts+=1;`.  What that does is it sets a variable on the server and keeps that variable so you can use it from any page within the same session.  You should probably read about sessions online though, because you also need to include `session_start()` at the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`$attempts` is always equal to one because it is not inside a loop, it is declared at the end and you are just adding one to its existing value (0). You need to put it in the appropriate place (just above the last `{` I think) and it should work.

Also, you seem to use different methods for adding one, such as `$black + 1` and `$attempts += 1;`. Use $variable++, it is much easier to understand and stops any errors arising of that.

Comment: I'm sorry, where should I put it?

Comment: I probably don't full understand your code, so when the user makes an incorrect guess, slip in '$attempts++' (and remove it from where it is atm)

Comment: actually, is there anyway to increase the attempt every time the user clicks 'submit' on the form?