# Counter variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable always resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677489/variable-always-resetting)

so I'm not too familiar with html or php, but I've been working on a game like mastermind, and one persistent problem I have been having with my code is that the variable $attempts seems to always reset, so that it's value is always 1. Is there a way to fix this? Most of my code is down here:

```
<?php
$showtable = false;
$showform = false;
$showstart= true;
$process = false;
$black = 0;
$white = 0;
$answer = array(1,2,3,4);
$tries = array();
$attempts = 0;

if (isset($_POST['started']))
{
    $showform = true;
    $showstart = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['guessed']))
{
    $process = true;
}

if ($showstart == true)
{
    echo"
    <form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='Start' name='start' />
    <input type='hidden' value='started' name='started'/>
    </form><Br /><br />
    ";
}

if ($showform == true)
{
    echo"
    <h3>Your guess:</h3>
    <form action='gogo.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Your guess' maxlength='4' value='' name='guess' />
    <input type='submit' value='guess' name='submitt' />
    <input type='hidden' value='started' name='started' />
    <input type='hidden' value='guessed' name='guessed' />
    </form><Br /><br />
    ";
}

if ($process == true)
{
    $attempts += 1;
    $guess = str_split($_POST['guess']);
    if ($guess == $answer)
    {
        $black = 4;
    } else
    {
        for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
        {
            if ($guess[$i] == $answer[$i])
            {
                $black += 1;
                $white -= 1;
            }
        }
        $result = array();
        foreach ($guess as $val)
        {
            if (($key = array_search($val, $answer))!==false)
            {
                $result[] = $val;
                unset($answer[$key]);
            }
        }
        $count = count($result);
        $white = $white + $count;
    }
}
$chance = implode(" ",$guess);
$try = $attempts.".".$chance.".".$white.".".$black;
array_push($tries, $try);
$showtable = true;

if ($showtable == true)
{
    echo"
    <table border='2' cellpadding='10'>
    <Tr><Td>Attempt:</td><td>Number guessed:</td><td>White:</td><Td>Black:</td></tr>
    ";
    for ($i=0;$i<$attempts;$i++)
    {
        $split = explode(".",$tries[$i]);
        echo"
        <tr><td>".$split[0]."</td><td>".$split[1]."</td><td>".$split[2]."</td>    <td>".$split[3]."</td></tr>
        ";
    }
    echo"
    </table>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you set `$attempts` to `0`, why do you expect it to be anything different? Use cookies or sessions.

Comment: really? where is it and how do I fix it?

Comment: @WaleedKhan sorry, but how should I implement it? I'm rather new at this

Comment: Does the page refresh after each guess? If so, the variables are always being reset on each page load so attempts will always start out as 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677489/variable-always-resetting -- It is not good to post a question twice at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of your code you initialise the variable to zero, so every time the code is run (namely every time a move is made) the variable is "reset".

You should save the variables somehow, either with a database or with a `$_SESSION` variable. But note that you will have to add checks to make sure that what's sent in `$_POST` is consistent with what you expect at this point in the game.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do i use the session variable?

Comment: @AnthonyWu http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

It's because every time you hit your page, you're setting `$attempts` to `0` at the beginning, and you're only ever increasing it by 1. As you aren't submitting (and then using) the value of `$attempts` in a form (hidden field or otherwise), you don't have any way of persisting that value from request to request. Remember, every time you visit a page, the script is starting over again from scratch. Unless you're storing things in a session or database, or using forms or query string parameters to persist the state of your data, expect to start over again each time.